# In PHP Version 5.6.3 read the file line by line and display in browser

Tags: php

I have a file "users_error.out" and it has the data like below.

```
users DoesNotExist
xyz
abc
123
```

want to display exactly same on the browser.
I am trying this in SuSE-11.4

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: foreach(file("users_error.out") as $line) {
   echo '<p>' . $line . '</p>' "\n";
}

I gave full path of the file and permissions are good like all the files in the directory
is this correct?

Comment: That would work, whats the issue? If you want it to look like a text file, you could just use `echo '<pre>'.file_get_contents('users_error.out').'</pre>';`

Comment: this is working but there is a dynamic variable in the file name as below and not working having the dynamic variable.

"/home/temp/$requestnumber-users_error.out"

Comment: Its unclear what your asking. If you got vars in the name then use concatenation or `"/home/temp/{$requestnumber}-users_error.out"` etc, good luck im out.

Comment: thank you for your time..tried  as echo '<pre>'.file_get_contents("/home/temp/{$requestnumber}-users_error.out").'</pre>'; - not working

Comment: single quote was appeared around the dynamic variable use the below function to remove the single quote.
str_replace( "'", "", "/home/temp/{$requestnumber}-users_error.out" )